# How to clone the global WP_Query object and change only one parameter?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've added a new `post_type` in my Wordpress installation and I would like to query that posts and use them in a loop.
The thing is that I have to manually build the arguments depending if it is a category page, or a tag page, etc.

Is there a way to reuse the already available global WP_Query object, modify the parameter `post_type` and run the query?

**This is what I want to avoid:**

```
$query = array(
  'post_type' => 'vehicle',
);

if( is_category() ){
  $query['category_name'] = get_query_var('category_name')
}

if( is_category() ){
  $query['category_name'] = get_query_var('category_name')
}

if( is_tag() ){
  $query['tag'] = get_query_var('tag')
}


// ... and so on

$loop = new WP_Query($query);
```

I don't want to use the `pre_get_posts` method because doing so will alter the global query, which is used for the rest of the website.

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed it like so:

```
$query = $wp_query->query_vars;

$query['post_type'] = 'vehicle';

$loop = new WP_Query($query);
```

I don't know if it is the right approach but it works for me.